# C++Builder 11.1 LSP does not work with classic Borland compiler

Tags: autocomplete, c++builder, c++builder-11-alexandria

Has LSP been removed for the classic Borland compiler in C++Builder 11.1?

Now it is marking error messages even in the includes of the VCL.

A new empty project shows errors, and LSP is not working with the classic Borland compiler.

Has anyone been able to try it? Is it a bug?

Comment: I haven't upgraded to a modern IDE version for awhile now, but just reading through some documentation. did LSP *ever* work for the classic compiler? The wording in [What's New in 10.3 Rio](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/What's_New#Better_code_completion_for_C.2B.2B) (when C++ LSP was introduced) and the latest [CodeInsight](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Code_Insight_Reference#Index_for_C.2B.2B_Insights) documentation suggest that LSP is only available for the Clang compilers.

Comment: Hi Remy, if it wasn't LSP it was autocomplete, but until version 11 it worked very well in classic c++ Builder and badly in CLang, now it doesn't work directly in classic and if in CLang, at least what worked should have been left as it was I think me.
My big projects are all in classic and they are more than 800 form, it is not feasible to convert them in clang at the moment, :-( if they don't solve it I will have to stay in 10.4 and not renew the subscription unfortunately.
I use a translator, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2):

Code Insight and code completion worked for the classic compiler up through RAD Studio 11.0.  It was broken for me in 11.1.  I submitted a bug report in the quality system: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-37665

Also, the LSP project options are only for the CLANG compilers.

Comment: Embarcadero released RAD Studio 11.1.5 today.  This problem appears fixed for me and my bug report was closed as resolved by the "sync service".

Answer (score 0):

I've 'upgraded' too! One annoyance from 11.0 in the IDE fixed (toolbar customization not working) to now in 11.1 no code completion using either the classic borland or clang compiler. I've stuck with Rad Studio since using version 1 in the 90's. Very disappointed!

edited data:
This solution is from Roy Nelson (not sure of affiliation)

1. Close your project.
2. Tools | Options | IDE | Environment Variables | [New...] Add a variable called "BDS_NO_LSP" (without quotes) and set the value to "T" also without quotes.
3. [OK]
4. [Save]
5. Restart the IDE

The downside is that the LSP will now not for Clang based projects.